# Warning: comparison of distinct pointer types

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

By mentioning the name of the array, we get the base address of the array which is same as the address of the 0th element of the array.

Hence i did this...

```
int main()
{
    int myArray[10] = { 1, 2 };

    if (myArray == &myArray == &myArray[0])
        printf("Address are equal!!!");

    return 0;
}
```

Program is not printing anything and I am getting the above mentioned warning.
Can anybody help me to understand this concept?
Thanks.

Comment: Enable the warnings of your compiler and fix them.

Comment: Use `&&` to combine boolean expressions.

Comment: `if (myArray == (int*)&myArray && (int*)&myArray == &myArray[0])`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, `myArray == &myArray == &myArray[0]` is not going to do what you expect.

Second, `&myArray` is of type `int (*)[10]` while `myArray` and `&myArray[0]` are of type `int *`. Both types are incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 3):

The condition in the if statement

```
if (myArray == &myArray == &myArray[0])
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( ( myArray == &myArray ) == &myArray[0])
```

In the first subexpression the left operand `myArray` has type `int *` because an array designator used in expressions is implicitly converted to pointer to the first element of the array.
The right operand `&myArray` points to the whole array declared like

```
int myArray[10] = { 1, 2 };
```

So its type is `int ( * )[10]`. 
Though the both pointers contain the same value that is the address of the extent of the memory occupied by the array nevertheless they have different types and there is no implicit conversion from one type to another. So the compiler should issue a diagnostic message.

But if the compiler will compile the code then the pointers have the same value and condition

```
( myArray == &myArray )
```

evaluates to `true`.

So you will get after evaluation of this condition

```
if ( true == &myArray[0])
```

It is obvious that `&myArray[0]` is not equal to 1 that corresponds to the arithmetic value of `true` after its conversion and the whole condition will evaluate to `false`.

So the if statement does not make sense.

You could write instead

```
if ( myArray == &myArray[0])
```

or the following way

```
if ( ( ( void * )myArray  == ( void * )&myArray ) && 
     ( ( void * )&myArray == ( void * )&myArray[0] ) )
```

Comment: `myArray == &myArray` does not evaluate to true.   It is an invalid comparison, since `myArray` is of type array of 10 `int` which, in an expression, is converted to a pointer to `int` (i.e. to an `int *`) while `&myArray` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`  (i.e. to an `int (*) [10]`).

Comment: @Peter  Please reread my answer one more before writing a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the equality operator `==` is a boolean (in C++) or a integer in C. So depending on which order the compiler is evaluating the whole thing (which BTW is implementation dependent) one of these comparisons is comparing an integer/boolean with a pointer. C allows you to compare integers with pointer. C++ does not.

The other problem with your code is, that the result of each of the subexpressions in your comparisons has a different type. `myArray` degrades to `(int*)` as does`&myArray[0]`, while `&myArray` *degrades* to `(int**)`, with the actual type being `int (*)[10]`.

Comment: *`&myArray` degrades to `(int**)`* ??

Comment: The `==` operator is left-to-right associative.  So `a == b == c` is equivalent to `(a == b) == c`

Comment: @haccks: `int **p = &myArray;` is valid.